# GROUP_CONCAT return multiple records

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have many tables and performing big query (about 5-7 LEFT JOINs).
Looks like this

```
SELECT *, t.id
GROUP_CONCAT(field SEPARATOR '|') AS fields,
GROUP_CONCAT(other SEPARATOR '|') AS others
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN tablefields tf ON t.id = tf.user_id
LEFT JOIN tableothers to ON t.id = to.user_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Here is problem. all fields concatting good, but two are **going like 'value|value|value|value' (15-17times)** even if only one row in the joined table.

What I do wrong?

P.S.

I can't use DISTINCT, because one field is section_id and other field is note. Note may be similar, but section_id is unique.

P.P.S

https://gist.github.com/3098105

Look part of query result.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tablename;
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
| id | user_id | section_id | note_data |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |    1331 | UserVideo  | test      |
|  2 |    1331 | UserNCAA   | test      |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I don't see a `GROUP BY` clause in your query ...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add. I can't show you direct query because of contract signed.

Comment: Check your data. If you have many multiple rows in your joined tables with the same id/user_id, you will get a value for each row.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I perform about 10 group_concats, 8 well, 2 (from table with one row!) goes value|value|value|value.....

Answer (score 5):

When you have multiple matching rows in both `tablefields` and `tableothers`, you are getting a cross product of the rows. (Which I believe is what Marcus Adams was getting at in his comment.)

If you are wanting a "list" from each of those tables, without generating any "duplicates", try something like this:

```
SELECT tt.id
     , tt.fields
     , GROUP_CONCAT(to.other ORDER BY to.other SEPARATOR '|') AS `others`
  FROM (SELECT t.id
             , GROUP_CONCAT(tf.field ORDER BY tf.field SEPARATOR '|') AS `fields`
          FROM table t
          LEFT JOIN tablefields `tf` ON t.id = tf.user_id
         GROUP BY t.id
       ) tt
  LEFT JOIN tableothers `to` ON tt.id = to.user_id
 GROUP BY tt.id, tt.fields
```

That inline view aliased as `tt` gets you the list from `tablefields`, on a single row for each `t.id`. That result set can then be joined to the `tableothers` table, to get the list from that table. Generating the resultset in this way avoids generating extra duplicates when there are multiple matching rows in each table, which would otherwise for a cross product.

---

You note that your are unable to make use of the `DISTINCT` keyword, because you have duplicate values in each list that you want to retain. If that weren't a requirement, if you could allow duplicate values to be eliminated, then you use the `DISTINCT` keyword, to get nearly the same result:

```
SELECT t.id
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tf.field ORDER BY tf.field SEPARATOR '|') AS `fields`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT to.other ORDER BY to.other SEPARATOR '|') AS `others`
  FROM table t
  LEFT JOIN tablefields `tf` ON t.id = tf.user_id
  LEFT JOIN tableothers `to` ON t.id = to.user_id
 GROUP BY t.id
```

This approach allows the generation of the cross product, but then eliminates ALL duplicates, both the duplicate values generated by a "cross product" operation, as well as those duplicates that exist in the native data.

Comment: It was the `DISTINCT` that did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

It is because of t.*. You should only select the columns for which you want to apply the grouping. Something like

```
SELECT t.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(field SEPARATOR '|') AS fields, 
GROUP_CONCAT(other SEPARATOR '|') AS others 
FROM table t 
LEFT JOIN tablefields tf ON t.id = tf.user_id 
LEFT JOIN tableothers to ON t.id = to.user_id 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, look SELECT in my query. Updated now.